# Integrand is indeterminant at bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

A friend and I are working on a calculus project and have stumbled onto a point of confusion. We have a function we are trying to evaluate at $a=0$:

$$ f(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(ax)}{\ln(x)} \,dx $$

While we know $f(0) = 0$ we don't fully understand why. Initially, we thought that since

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(0)}{\ln(x)} \,dx = \int_{0}^{1} 0 \,dx = 0$$

However, we are confused with the evaluation of the integrand at $x = 1$ without the simplification, as it evaluates to an indeterminate form:

$$ \frac{\sin(0)}{\ln(1)} = \frac{0}{0}$$

How do we solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You assign value first or you do integration first?

Comment: The integral doesn't have a closed-form solution so we plug in the value of "a" first.

Comment: @Water you can only do that if you first prove the integral converges. Not having a closed form solution is not an excuse. How could you prove convergence/divergence around $x=1$ ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. My gut reaction would be to use a limit for the integral (I assume it's improper). But I don't know where I would go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $$f(a)=\lim_{b \to 0^+,c^{\mathbf -} \to 1^-}\int_b^c\frac{\sin (ax)}{\ln x}dx$$. For $b>0,c<1,b \le c,$, $$\frac{0}{\ln x}=0 \text{ for all }x \in [b,c]$$ $$\text{ Thus }f(0)=\lim_{b \to 0^+,c \to 1^-}\int_b^ c 0 dx=0.$$